# How can i terminate application on adf mobile

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile

How can i exit by terminating the application by using application menu on adf mobile platform. I m expecting adf mobile can be supplied for 2 platforms IOS and Android.
brgds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java script API

```
navigator.app.exitApp();
```